# VSCode pylint not highlighting unused arguments

Tags: python, pylint

I have the following method

```py
def foo(bar):
    print("hello world")
```

Edit: Running pylint in VSCode

[expected behavior]
pylint highlights 'bar' as an unused variable

[Actual Behaviour]
From VScode output

```sh
##########Linting Output - pylint##########

--------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 10.00/10 (previous run: 10.00/10, +0.00)
```

I have no additional pylint config setup

Comment: Did u execute pylint in command line? When I did it, I had the result
`W0613: Unused argument 'bar' (unused-argument)`

Comment: Something is wrong with your setup or with how you are running pylint.  Pylint correctly gives me three errors for your code: blacklisted variable name 'foo,' blacklisted variable name 'bar,' and unused argument 'bar.'

Comment: How are you running pylint, I mean in Terminal or in any IDE?

Comment: Issue is in VSCode only. I have updated the question above. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out there is a setting in VSCode that enforces minimal checkers
`Python › Linting: Pylint Use Minimal Checkers`

Answer (score 0):

I found this in [pylint documentation](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html):

> **possibly-unused-variable (W0641):**
>
> Possibly unused variable %r Used when a variable is defined but might not be used. The possibility comes from the fact that locals() might be used, which could consume or not the said variable

In your case, probably because you haven't use the `bar` argument inside your function. If you are not using it, just remove it for a cleaning code.

Check the oficial [VS Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting) about linting if you want to change this settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install `pylint` with `pip install -U pylint`
and then install the `pylint` extension in vscode